# TYPO3 9.5 Extbase Query for UidArray

Tags: sql, repository, extbase, typo3-9.x

I´ve got the following SQL-Query

```
    $uidArray = explode(",", $uids);
        foreach ($uidArray as $uid) {
            $dynamicUid[] = '`uid` LIKE \''.$uid.'\'';
        }
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->statement("SELECT * FROM `tx_myextension_domain_model_thi` WHERE ".implode($dynamicUid, " OR "));
        return $query->execute();
```

This works fine but I want to have it like this:

```
 $uidArray = explode(",", $uids);
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        foreach ($uidArray as $key => $value) {
            $constraints[] =  $query->equals('uid', $value);
        }
        return $query->matching(
            $query->logicalAnd($constraints)
        )->execute();
```

Here I get the following Output with the Query Parser :

```
'SELECT `tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.* FROM `tx_myextension_domain_model_thi` 
`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi` 
WHERE ((`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`uid` = :dcValue1) AND 
(`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`uid` = :dcValue2)) AND 
(`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`sys_language_uid` IN (0, -1)) AND 
(`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`pid` = 0) AND 
((`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`deleted` = 0) AND (
`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`t3ver_state` <= 0) AND 
(`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`pid` <> -1) AND 
(`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`hidden` = 0) AND 
(`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`starttime` <= 1607084460) AND 
((`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`endtime` = 0)
    OR (`tx_myextension_domain_model_thi`.`endtime` > 1607084460)))'
```

And the Uids as dcValue-Array.

```
   dcValue1 => '1' (1 chars)
   dcValue2 => '2' (1 chars)
```

Maybe someone can help me to rewrite this, because unfortunately I can't get any further!

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the result of your execute?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas the result without statement is empty -> I get the following with the query parser (please see edited question because its too much for comment section!

Comment: in which page Id are your objects stored? It looks like that the query searched for the pid 0. Which TYPO3 version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the in operator?

```
 public function yourFunctionName($uid) 
 {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->in('uid', $uidArray);
   return $query->execute();
 }
```

Assuming that your array looks like this:

```
$uidArray = [
  0 = '34',
  1 = '15',
  3 = '88'
]
```

**EDIT**

If you do not care about where your objects are stored then you can do the following.

```
public function yourFunctionName($uid) 
{
   $query = $this->createQuery();
   $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
   $query->matching(
       $query->in('uid', $uidArray)
   );
  return $query->execute()];
 }
```

Which is going to ignore the `pid` in the query

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, yes I have tried but unfortunately without success.

`
array(2 items)
   0 => '1' (1 chars)
   1 => '2' (1 chars)
`

Comment: That works with return $query->execute();
I use TYPO3 9.5.22 and the objects arent stored in PID 0, didnt know that I have to set them in the repository too. I set it only in setup and constants.ts

But thank you very much! :)